# In which order the array names will print the keys in TCL?

Tags: arrays, hash, tcl

Could any one please let me know, how the hash function works in tcl arrays.

```
for {set i 1} {$i<21} {incr i} {
    set a($i) $i
}
set a(30) $i
puts [lindex [split [array statistics a] \n] 0]
puts [array names a]
```

for this program i am getting the output as below.

```
21 entries in table, 16 buckets
17 18 1 20 19 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 30 12 13 14 15 16
```

i want to know, in which order the keys are printing here.

Answer (score 1):

The `array names` command produces the keys of the array in “arbitrary” order. It's actually the current natural iteration order of the underlying hash table, which can change as the array grows, and is actually extremely difficult to explain other than by reference to the implementation and the history of the array. Because it is so difficult, we just tend to say “random”; it's not, but it might as well be (for purposes other than generating random numbers; it'd be a *terrible* PRNG). It's always worked like this. The other `array` subcommands will use the same order, especially `array get` and the very-rarely-used iterator subcommands.

If you want a particular order, you have to sort them yourself. The `lsort` command might be useful for that. Or you can use a `dict`; those maintain insertion order (but are technically values, and so you can't `trace` an element or `upvar` to it).